# "error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector" when trying to use switch()

Tags: c

In my understanding, what switch() does is that it takes the expression within the brackets and compares it to the cases listed within switch() and executes the ones that match. Why would this require the expression inputted to be a pointer or array?
This is from a school assignment and I couldn't find other cases where switch() showed an error because the expression wasnt a pointer.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define LENGTH 30
void printArray(char a[], int length){
    int i;
    printf("[");
    for (i=0; i<length; i++){
        if (i!= length-1){
            if (a[i]=='\0'){
                printf("\\0,");
            }
            else if (a[i]=='\n'){
                printf("\\n,");
            }
            else{
                printf("%c,",a[i]);
            }
        }
        else if (i == length-1){
            if (a[i]=='\0'){
                printf("\\0");
            }
            else if (a[i]=='\n'){
                printf("\\n");
            }
            else{
                printf("%c",a[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("]\n");
}

void printString(char str[]){
    int length = strlen(str),i;
    putchar('\"');
    for (i=0;i<length;i++){
        putchar(str[i]);
    }
    putchar('\"');
}

void readLine(char str[], int length){
    int i;
    char c;
    while(c!='\n'){
        c=getchar();
        str[i]=c;
        i++;
    }
    str[i]='\0';
}
int main()
{
    char string1[12] = "hello", string2[12] = "hello\n", string3[12] = "hello\n\0you\n", string4[12] = "0123456789AB";
    char inputString;
    do{
        printf("Command [qpasoirR123]? ");
        readLine(inputString, LENGTH);
        switch (inputString[0]){
        case 'q':
            printf("Bye!\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("Unknown command '%c'\n", inputString[0]);
            break;
        }
    } while (inputString[0]!='q');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char inputString;` is not an array. You cannot use `inputString[0]`.

Comment: `char inputString;` is a plain single character. Applying the subscript-Operator `[]` as in `inputString[0]` is not useful. You're also trying to read multiple character into a single character.

Comment: Replace ```char inputstring; ``` by ```char inputstring[LENGTH];```

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use the options: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std-gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results.  compiling the posted code results in 14 warning and error messages.  Also, the statement: `#include <string.h>` ( for the `strlen()` function) is missing

Comment: @moi it worked thanks. could you explain why i had to specify a length for inputstring?

Comment: @bck I wrote up an explanation below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my understanding, what switch() does is that it takes the expression within the brackets and compares it to the cases listed within switch() and executes the ones that match.

Yes and it must be an integer expression.

> Why would this require the expression inputted to be a pointer or array?

It doesn't. The compiler is just saying that this code doesn't make any sense:

```
char inputString;
...
inputString[0]
```

inputString needs to be an array or pointer or you can't write `[ ]`...

Comment: can it only be an integer and not a character? I've read some online examples where they used characters for the switch and not integers.

Comment: @bck Character constants like `'A'` are actually of integer type in C (unlike C++ where they are `char`).

Answer (score 0):

Consider `switch (inputString[0]){`

`switch` requires an integer type (char, short, int, long) as argument. `char` is acceptable as it is an integer type (signed 1-byte)

`char inputString;` states that inputString is a char value. Now, `inputString[0]` implies 0 offset in memory from pointer inputString.

For `inputString[0]` to be valid, you need to define `char *inputString;` However, while you have defined a pointer, it is not pointing to valid memory.

Hence you define an array - such as - `inputString[LENGTH]` - now you have a valid allocation of `LENGTH` bytes starting at `inputString`

`readline` can now read in `LENGTH` bytes to memory location `inputString` and your switch statement uses the first char at this memory location.